Dart language flutter Raised button not working

Undefined name 'RaisedButton'. (Documentation)
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. in Flutter Dart version 2.19.6
The Save button is not sliding in
here is my Code

 AnimatedContainer(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      width: isDirty ? 100 : 0,
      height: 42,
      curve: Curves.decelerate,
      child: RaisedButton.icon(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(100),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
          ),
        ),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.done,
        ),
        label: Text(
          getTranslated(context, 'SAVE'),
          style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1),
        ),
        onPressed: handleSave,
      ),
    )

I tried changing to ElevatedButton failed to work
I tried changing to OutlinedButton failed to work
I tried changing to TextButton but failed
I searched on google the solution provided is not working for me

ElevatedButton is the replacement, but it has different parameters.

If you want to use ElvatedButton. You have to remove the shape, background color, and text color and instead use ElevatedButton.styleFrom like below code:
ElevatedButton.icon(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(100),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100))),),
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.done,
    ),
    label: Text(
      getTranslated(context, 'SAVE'),
      style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1),
    ),
    onPressed: handleSave,
),

